# Connecting two PC's together

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, connection

I want to connect my Laptop with the Desktop PC. Is it possible to use same ethernet Cat5 cable? All I want is to browse the directory from my laptop on to the desktop and copy some files. Something like a true connection between two computers.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You will need to get what is known as a [cross over cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable), or simply an adapter which does the same job.

[image]

If you are lucky and your networking card(s) are new enough, you may be able to use a standard cable as some can tell when they are connected direct to another computer and basically configure themselves for crossover mode automatically.

Once connected, simply set up networking / run the wizard / run Homegroup wizard as you would on any normal network and it should be working in no time.

Hope this helps, if it is your first network or you need additional help on settings, either post another question or edit your original one and I (or someone else) will be happy to help!

Comment: Thanks Wil, Do I need two of these crossover adapters? i.e. one for the laptop and one for the desktop and then join them with cat5?

Comment: @Zai No, you'll only need 1 crossover adapter.

Comment: @Zai, @Mokubai is correct, just one... otherwise I think it will switch it back to a regular cable? (Can't visualise properly today, need more sleep!)